# Linux cp with a regexp

Tags: regex, linux, cp

I would like to copy some files in a directory, renaming the files but conserving extension. Is this possible with a simple `cp`, using regex ?

For example :

```
cp ^myfile\.(.*) mydir/newname.$1
```

So I could copy the file conserving the extension but renaming it. Is there a way to get matched elements in the `cp` regex to use it in the command ?
If not, I'll do a perl script I think, or if you have another way...

Thanks

Comment: Does the new name somehow derive from the old name? Can you say the concrete situation, maybe it can be done with simple shell substitution.

Comment: Sure. The new name doesn't have a link with the old... A real example :
    cp treepict_313* dir/foobar.$1
foobar is a name given by a website user, it can be anything then. I just rename the file with the desired name before the user download it... To not let a formatted name as treepict_300.ext... Is this clearer ?

Comment: Or maybe you want to rename `a.c`, `a.s`, `a.o`, `a.h` and `a.bak` to `b.c`, `b.s`, `b.o`, `b.h` and `b.bak` ?

Comment: That's it, but copying it in another directory in the same time (i mean, keeping a.c, a.s, a.o, a.h and a.bak)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Suppose you have `myfile.a`, `myfile.b`, `myfile.c`:

```
for i in myfile.*; do echo mv "$i" "${i/myfile./newname.}"; done
```

This creates (upon removal of `echo`) `newname.a`, `newname.b`, `newname.c`.

Comment: @Ray: Substitution solves 90% of my file handling needs and is the prime reason for having a Bash in Windows! :-)

Answer (score 1):

The shell doesn't understand general regexes; you'll have to outsource to auxiliary programs for that. The classical scripty way to solve your task would be something like

```
for a in myfile.* ; do
  b=`echo $a | sed 's!^myfile!mydir/newname!'`
  cp $a $b
done
```

Or have a perl script generate a list of commands that you then source into the shell.

Answer (score 1):

I really like the regex syntax of the `rename` perl script (by Robin Barker and Larry Wall), e.g.:

> `rename "s/OldFile/NewFile/" OldFile*`
>
> `OldFile.c` and `OldFile.h` are renamed to `NewFile.c` and `NewFile.h`, respectively

I simply wanted the exact same thing with a copy command:

`copy "s/OldFile/NewFile/" OldFile*`

So I duplicated that script and changed the rename statement to copy via `File::Copy`. Et voila! A copy command with perl-regex syntax:

https://gist.github.com/jcward/0ead33bd79f2061c68728cc82582241f