# Using `cp`, how can I use a regex match in the source in the destination

Tags: regex, unix, cp

I have a directory with files that are named like this.

```
basic.js
basic.json
basic.html
basic.text
basic_contents.json
```

I'd like to copy in one command, all of these files to

```
diff_name.js
diff_name.json
diff_name.html
diff_name.text
diff_name_contents.json
```

I'd like to do something like `cp basic(.*)$ diff_name$1` but that doesn't work. Is there any way to do this in one command, preferably using `cp`? I am tired of manually typing every single line manually.

Thanks!

Comment: Some suggestions here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7135324/linux-cp-with-a-regexp

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's possible in the way you mean it (using wildcards and replacements), but I'd do it like this:

```
$> for file in `ls`; do cp "${file}" "not_${file}"; done
```

Comment: Thank you! Sorry, but there is no guarantee that the original name is a part of the final name. I've updated my question to reflect this. It's usually not just a prepending of not_, it is usually a completely different name.

Answer (score 0):

Use this simple script

```
#!/bin/bash/
for file in  basic*
do
   cp $file diff_name${file}
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#for every file matching pattern
for f in basic_*
do
     #rename file, replacing first occurrence match for "basic"
     echo cp -v $f ${f/basic/diff_name}
done
```

More on [bash string manipulation](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html)